# How to edit post meta data on Wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post-meta

I am trying to edit the post meta data on my Wordpress blog to include:

**Author(no link) Date(no link)  Page(with affiliate link to page on my site)**

under every Post Title.

I am using the Activello theme and have installed a child theme. I am trying to create a function to do this post meta data.

This is what is there right now (this posts the author and date with a link):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'activello_posted_on' ) ) :
  function activello_posted_on() {
    printf( '<div class="post-meta"><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a> <a href="%3$s">%4$s</a></div>',
      esc_url( get_permalink() ),
      esc_html( get_the_date() ),
      esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
      get_the_author()
    );
  }
endif;
```

I have tried to work on this and something is still not right with my code as I am getting an error. PLEASE HELP!

```
     if ( ! function_exists( 'activello_posted_on' ) ) :
      function activello_posted_on() {
        printf( __(‘%1$s by %2$s <a href=“%3$s”>%4$s</a>’),
          get_the_date(), 
          get_the_author(),
          esc_url( get_permalink() ),
          esc_html( '<a href="http://www.diyandkawa.com/legalities/“>This post contains affiliate links.</a>' );

    );
  }
endif;
```

If someone could please help, I would really appreciate it!